# Make the Help Center pages consistent with regards to hyphens and dashes

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, grammar

The Help Center pages are inconsistent with regard to the dashes being used. Currently, you will find all three of those:

- The hyphen-minus (-)
- The en-dash (–)
- The em-dash (—)

Let's look at these examples:

- [Why is voting important?](https://superuser.com/help/why-vote) (uses hyphen-minus and en-dashes)
- [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://superuser.com/help/tagging) (uses en- and em-dashes)
- [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers) (uses hyphen-minus)

Please make this consistent:

- Do not use the hyphen here, as it should only be used in compound words or word division.
- Use either the en- or em-dash in *all* occurrences.

<sub>While you're at it, the [What are tags](https://superuser.com/help/tagging) page mentions:</sub>

> <sub>Replace spaces with dashes (-) …</sub>

<sub>But this is not a dash—it's a hyphen-minus. If I enter a tag with an en-dash, e.g. `[testing–tag]`, the tag gets split at the dash.</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've fixed the pages you used as examples and will go through the rest of the pages shortly.